# Index action dislplays all metadata at end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ROR and trying simple BookReview app, i see that my index action shows all metadata at the end.

Here is my controller action:

```
    def index
    @books = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

Here is the index.html.erb loop

```
<%=  @books.each do |b| %>
    <h1><%= link_to b.title, book_path(b) %></h1>
    <p>Author: <%= b.author %></p>

<% end %>
```

here is the output i'm getting at browser:

[image]

How to avoid printing those extra lines at bottom?

Answer (score 1):

```
<% @books.each do |b| %>
    <h1><%= link_to b.title, book_path(b) %></h1>
    <p>Author: <%= b.author %></p>
<% end %>

remove = in <%= @books.each do |b| %>
```

Comment: Then accept my answer :) @praneeth